# Single Table Inheritance rails has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord, single-table-inheritance

I have a model called Course which needs to be associated with exams and assignments. I want to able to write code like this:

```
>>c = Course.new
>>assignment1 = c.assignments << Assignment.new
>>exam1 = c.exams << Exam.new
```

c.assessments should now include both exam1 and assignment1

How I think this should be accomplished (using single table inheritance from the Assessment model):

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assessments
  attr_accessible :title, :name, :startDate, :endDate, :color
end

class Assessment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  attr_accessible :end_at, :name, :start_at, :type, :weight
end

class Assignment < Assessment
end

class Exam < Assessment
end
```

I've tried my best to find out how to do this but i cant seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Course has only assesments associations so you should be able to write code like this:

```
c = Course.new
c.assesments << Assignment.new
c.assesments << Exam.new
```

Also make sure that assesments table has type column with datatype string.

Comment: This does seem like my best option.